# Combining Objects into a new model with Linq/Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am working on a Blazor Project and using Dapper to Pull Data from a SQL Db.
I am pulling 3 tables at the moment. An entity table, a specialty table and a bridge table that is there to maintain the many to many relationship between entity and specialties.

I am able to pull from SQL fine and I want to combine the data in my data service and inject it as a new object model to the Blazor component.

Here are the models:

**Entity**

```
public class EntityModel : IEntityModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PhysicianId { get; set; }
        public int PartnerId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Specialty**

```
 public class SpecialtyModel : ISpecialtyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**BridgeModel**

```
public class BridgeModel : IBridgeModel
    {
        public int Id1 { get; set; }
        public int Id2 { get; set; }
    }
```

I made the properties in the bridge model generic so I could use it with another bridge table I have for a many to many relationship. The bridge tables are just two columns of IDs that link their respective tables. In this case Entity.Id and Specialty.Id

Here is the model I am combining all the information into:

```
 public class CombinedModel : ICombinedModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PhysicianId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<ISpecialtyModel> Specialties { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the inside of my data service where I am stuck trying to combine the data with Linq and Lambda expressions.

```
 public async Task<List<IEntityModel>> ReadEntities()
        {
            var entities = await _dataAccess.LoadData<EntityModel, dynamic>("dbo.spEntity_Read", new { }, "SqlDb");
            return entities.ToList<IEntityModel>();
        }

        public async Task<List<ISpecialtyModel>> ReadSpecialties()
        {
            var specialties = await _dataAccess.LoadData<SpecialtyModel, dynamic>("dbo.spSpecialty_Read", new { }, "SqlDb");
            return specialties.ToList<ISpecialtyModel>();
        }

        public async Task<List<IBridgeModel>> ReadEntitySpecialtyBridge()
        {
            var bridge = await _dataAccess.LoadData<BridgeModel, dynamic>("dbo.spEntitySpecialty_Read", new { }, "SqlDb");
            return bridge.ToList<IBridgeModel>();
        }

        public async Task<List<ICombinedModel>> CombineData()
        {
            var entities = await ReadEntities();
            var specialties = await ReadSpecialties();
            var bridge = await ReadEntitySpecialtyBridge();

            //var combined = (from e in entities
            //                join b in bridge on e.Id equals b.Id1
            //                join s in specialties on b.Id2 equals s.Id
            //                select new CombinedModel()
            //                {
            //                    Id = e.Id,
            //                    PhysicianId = e.PhysicianId,
            //                    FirstName = e.FirstName,
            //                    LastName = e.LastName,
            //                    Specialties = new List<ISpecialtyModel>()
            //                });

            var combined = (from e in entities
                            select new CombinedModel
                            {
                                Id = e.Id,
                                PhysicianId = e.PhysicianId,
                                FirstName = e.FirstName,
                                LastName = e.LastName,
                                Specialties = specialties.Where(s =>  )
                            }
                            );

            return combined.ToList<ICombinedModel>();
```

This is where I am stuck. How can I write this Linq query to combine this data into the new model?

I am able to get data passed into the razor component but I am not combining it correctly and this is where I am stuck.

I hope someone can shed some light on the matter. Thank you for taking the time to look over this, I appreciate it.

With Thanks,
Cesar

Comment: Is there a reason you're not writing the SQL to join the data appropriately and then reading it in a single query? Dapper does support this functionality, although it looks like you may be using stored procedures and that might not be supported

Comment: So with the query I have written using Sql I do get all the values returned with repeated data, but I am not sure how I would use dapper to pull that data, into an object. 



So I thought well let me pull each table and then combine them when they are loaded in memory. I am not sure if this is a bad idea, but this won't be a very large database.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.tritac.com/nl/blog/dappernet-by-example/
The key takeaway is the `Query<Account, Shop, Account>` and the `splitOn: "ShopId"`

Comment: Would I have to change my Db design? Each table has just an Id and their properties. 

But I use a bridge table to resolve the many to many relationship so I map an the entity ID to the specialty ID.

Comment: *So I thought well let me pull each table and then combine them when they are loaded in memory. I am not sure if this is a bad idea* - given that a a database's entire raison d'etre is to track and manipulate related data, treating it like some data bucket that you load completely into c# and do all your processing there is a bit like buying a car and then pushing it to the store so you can load your shopping into it and push it home again

Comment: @CypherBlue You shouldn't have to change your DB design. It is just based off of what is being selected I believe. As you can see in the examples, the select parameters are grouped up nicely which allows this to work the way it works

Comment: @CaiusJard well your comment didn't come off as helpful. In this case I don't see the point of this. I am basically building a directory web app where one can browse to see all these records at once, so they are all going to be loaded into memory regardless.

Comment: @JoePhillips Thank you let me give it a shot.

Comment: C#'s design focus and a database's design focus are completely different. C# can join data, and SQL Server can be abused into doing loads of things C# would do - but it doesn't mean we should. Databases are incredibly good at connecting data together; a "well the app is going to download all this data anyway"isn't a good justification for doing the connecting in the app. Also, humans do tend to want to see huge amounts of data but they aren't very good at dealing with it; providing a search and loading a small amount of data, or (slightly worse) a progressive nav is better than a huge list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to process locally (doing on the server should eliminate the need to pull `bridge` over from the database, and if `bridge` contains records that aren't relevant to `entities` could potentially be a lot of unnecessary data traffic) then you just need to filter `specialties` by the correct `bridge` records for a given entity:

```
var combined = (from e in entities
                select new CombinedModel {
                    Id = e.Id,
                    PhysicianId = e.PhysicianId,
                    FirstName = e.FirstName,
                    LastName = e.LastName,
                    Specialties = specialties.Where(s => bridge.Where(b => b.Id1 == e.Id).Select(b => b.Id2).Contains(s.Id)).ToList()
                });
```

Depending on the size of `specialties` and `entities`, it might be worthwhile to pre-process `bridge` to make access for a given entity more efficient (`Where` is O(n) so `specialties.Where` x `bridge.Where` is O(n*m)):

```
var bridgeDict = bridge.GroupBy(b => b.Id1).ToDictionary(bg => bg.Key, bg => bg.Select(b => b.Id2).ToHashSet());
var combined = (from e in entities
                let eBridge = bridgeDict[e.Id]
                select new CombinedModel {
                    Id = e.Id,
                    PhysicianId = e.PhysicianId,
                    FirstName = e.FirstName,
                    LastName = e.LastName,
                    Specialties = specialties.Where(s => eBridge.Contains(s.Id)).ToList()
                });
```

Comment: Thank you so much!